# How to have a button in Magento, Which opens an Other Site URL?

Tags: magento

am new to magento. how to have a button ,instead of add to cart button on product page. That button has to open a URL in a new window,which i mentioned in an attribute. Each product has different URL according to the product.kindly help in this issue

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To have the button in the product page you will have to copy the file:

for 1.9: `app/design/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

for previous: `app/design/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

You can then copy it to: `app/design/[your_package]/[your_theme]/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

In this template file, you create the button HTML and call in the attribute with

```
$this->getYourAttributeKey();
```

So for example, if you had the URL in the attribute, you could call the URL from the product and into the button by doing something like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Put Your Text Here" onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $this->getYourAttributeKey(); ?>'" />
```

**Note**
If your attribute's key is something like "my_attribute_code_here", when you are calling it from the template, remove the underscores and make each letter upper case. Magento will use it's "magic getters" to pull the information it needs from the object. So:

```
my_attribute_code_here == $this->getMyAttributeCodeHere();
```

Comment: Hi Richard Cripps, I tried as what you said here, But the page reloads when clicking the button **<input type="button" value="Get Code" onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $this->getCouponStoreUrl(); ?>'" />**

Comment: Have you checked to see if the URL is being pulled through correctly? Inspect the element and check the URL is there in full.